# What is the mathematical definition of the latent space

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, autoencoder

I have been seeking a mathematical explanation of the latent space of a neural network. The best I have gotten is "The latent space is the space in which the data lies in the bottleneck layer." However, what do we mean by "the space in which..." rigorously speaking?

Comment: Vector space, but, what beyond that are you asking?